# Quick question on a geometric translation.

Tags: calculus, geometry, functions

I am following the text *Advanced Calculus* by Lynn H. Loomis and Shlomo Sternberg.

> [image]

In this passage why is $y = f(x)$ iff $s = f(a+t) -f(a)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,
$$s=y-f(a)\qquad\qquad t=x-a$$
Therefore,
$$f(a+t)=f(a+(x-a))=f(x)$$
so that
$$f(a+t)-f(a)=f(x)-f(a)$$
Thus,
$$s=f(a+t)-f(a)\iff s=f(x)-f(a)$$
and $s=y-f(a)$, so
$$s=f(x)-f(a)\iff y-f(a)=f(x)-f(a)\iff y=f(x)$$